# VB 2010 search CSV records - match search term to return records

Tags: vb.net, search, csv, match, records

I have a csv file with 8 fields and multiple records. 
I would like to search the ID field (the first field) by entering a search term in a text box, find the matching record/s and display the full record/s on the VB form in a multi-line text box. I would also like to search by date to find all dates ending in a given year e.g. 2009, with all matching full record/s being returned. 
I’ve got so far with the code below, and can return all data in the file but haven’t been able to achieve the search – I tried the commented-out IF statement but couldn’t get it working. 
Sample CSV follows the code below.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnSearchName_Click(sender As System.Object,...

    Dim fileIn As String
    Dim fileRows(), fileFields() As String

    fileIn = "C:\SuppliersSearch_Test\suppliers.csv"

    Label1.Text = String.Empty

    If IO.File.Exists(fileIn) Then
        Dim fileStream As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fileIn)
        fileRows = fileStream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
        For i As Integer = 0 To fileRows.Length - 1
            fileFields = fileRows(i).Split(",")
            If fileFields.Length >= 8 Then

                ' ?? loop to see if field0 contains the inputted surname, return the record
                'then check the next record until ALL records checked and matching ones returned

        ‘ if fileFields(0) = txtSearch.text then

                txtResults.Text += fileFields(0) & ", " & fileFields(1) & ", " & fileFields(3) & ", " & fileFields(4) & ", " & fileFields(5) & ", " & fileFields(6) & ", " & fileFields(7)


            End If
        Next
    Else
        txtResults.Text = fileIn & " not found."
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

Sample CSV data. To aid clarity, each record ends with ".com":

> Supp1,1 Blue,1  Socks,01/01/2008,1 SocksSupplier,1 Socks supp
>   address,1 Socks phone,1 Socks@socks.com Supp2,2 Pink,2
>   Shoes,01/05/2009,2 ShoesSupplier,2 Shoes supp address,2 Shoes supp
>   phone,2 Shoes@shoes.com Supp3,3 Red,3 Bag,04/03/2009,3 BagSupplier,3
>   Bag supplier adress,3 Bag supp phone,3 bags@bags.com Supp4,4 Gren,4
>   Tie,05/03/2007,4 TieSupplier,4 Tie Supplier address,4 Tie supp phone,4
>   tie_supp@ties.com Supp5,5 Grey,5 Suit,13/05/2009,5 SuitSupplier,5 Suit
>   Supplier address,5 Suit supp phone,5 suitsupp@suits.com Supp6,6
>   Black,6 Skirt,14/05/2008,6 SkirtSupplier,6 Skirt Supplier address,6
>   Skirt supp phone,6 skirtsupp@skirts.com